# Ml kit never detect more than 2 QrCode in an image

Tags: android, firebase-mlkit

I am currently writing a real time QrCode detector through Camera in a Mobile device.

I want to be able to detect all QrCode in a frame, but ML kit never detects more than two QrCode in a frame.

There is an option of `FirebaseVisionBarcodeDetector` or some thinking like that, for detecting more than tow QrCode in the same image?